# Trim up to n 0s

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013

I have a calculated value (in column H) which gives the number of trailing `0`s I'd like to trim from the right of a cell (column E). But I only want to remove `0`s; if there are other characters they should remain.

Examples:

```
E |    H    | Output
--+---------+--------
3 | 0110A00 | 0110A
3 | 0110A0B | 0110A0B
1 | 0110A00 | 0110A0
```

Any ideas? I'd like to avoid macros or masses of nested `IF`s if possible.

Comment: How about a User defined function "TrimRightZeros" that takes as an imput a string and returns a string with no right zeros.  you can while loop the value passed in and iterate for each letter from the right while 0.

Comment: @xQbert It wouldn't be hard to code up a customized version of `RTrim`, but I'd like to avoid VBScript if possible.

Comment: So you're looking for a formula specfic answer... which I now see as a tag... sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=LEFT(H1,MAX(AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(H1)))/(MID(H1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(H1))),1)<>"0"),1),LEN(H1)-E1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. I'm going to have to study these to learn the underlying method and add to my bag of tricks.